# Tapestry 5 and JQuery-ui : Page is sometimes not displayed correctly

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tapestry

I work on a tapestry5 project, using javascript and jquery-ui.
It happens sometimes that, after a server restart, a page is not displayed correctly. And this does not depend on the browser you're using. I noticed the same behaviour with different browsers.

And no matter what other pages you might open, the problem is till the same, and the jquery-ui components are not loaded as expected.

After restarting the server again, I get the normal display I was expecting, with all the jquery-ui displayed correctly (tabs, etc)

Does anyone have an idea what is the root cause of this problem?

NB: I'm very new to Tapestry. Please tell me if this is a normal behaviour of the web application (although I'm not convinced with that :( )

**UPDATE :** 
By the normal display, I mean jquery-ui tabs being displayed as expected. See following screenshot (blur effect is on purpose for some company privacy issues) : 
[image]

However the page is sometimes displayed as following : 
[image]

Sometimes the page just keeps looking like this until it's entirely loaded. But sometimes, it doesn't recover unless I restart the server. 
In fact, both behaviors are not wanted.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all normal, but I don't think you've given enough information about the symptoms yet. In what way is the page not displayed correctly? Have you used the browser developer tools (usually F12) to determine whether the JavaScript files that you are expecting to be downloaded are really getting downloaded?

Comment: Please check my update. I added screenshots. I would be very thankful if you could help me out. Thanks

Comment: You've probably already solved this problem by now, but if not: please use the browser developer tools (F12), especially the Network feature, to determine whether the JavaScript and CSS files that you are expecting to be downloaded are really getting downloaded.